# CanCan explanation of load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I would know how the `load_and_authorize_resource` works inside.
I searched the github page [Link](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/ff2b632f1524bac4273fe113968d73ea62114652/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L357) and tried to undestand , but i didn't find nothing usefull. I only understand that `load_and_authorize_resource` is like a before_filter and it loads (in some way) the ability that we have written in ability.rb

I would know better how this is possible. I mean, i don't want to study ALL the gem, but i want just to see how cancan load the ability of a resource in a controller and if the `load_and_authorize_resource` is really a sort of before_filter.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**disclaimer**: for the sake of simplicity, I omit some calls to short inner methods intentionally. The full chain of calling can be obtained by following `load_and_authorize_resource` method definition and so forth.

As stated in documentation, `load_and_authorize_resource` sets up a `before_filter`...

```
# cancan/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb
def load_and_authorize_resource(*args)
  cancan_resource_class.add_before_filter(self, :load_and_authorize_resource, *args)
end
```

...which calls two methods: `load_resource` and `authorize_resource`.

```
# cancan/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb
def load_and_authorize_resource
  load_resource
  authorize_resource
end
```

To get the idea of their behaviour we're going to look at both of them closely.

Based on `params` hash which was passed to your controller action, `load_resource` makes a decision on whether it should obtain a new instance of a class (e.g. `Post.new`) or `find` a particular instance based on `params[:id]` (e.g. `Post.find(params[:id])`). That instance (or a collection of instances for actions like `index`) is assigned to corresponding instance variable of your controller action.

```
# cancan/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb
def load_resource
  unless skip?(:load)
    if load_instance?
      # here you have obtained your object, e.g. Post with id=5
      # and placed it into cancan resource_instance variable.
      # it has automatically set up @post instance variable for you
      # in your action
      self.resource_instance ||= load_resource_instance
    elsif load_collection?
      self.collection_instance ||= load_collection
    end
  end
end
```

Later on, `authorize_resource` gets called. Its inner logics syntax should be familiar to you: checking abilities by hands looks just the same as what happens inside of this method. Basically you take a `resource_instance` obtained at the previous step, `params[:action]` which is the name of a current action, and check if particular action can be accessed for given object(s).

```
# cancan/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb
def authorize_resource
  unless skip?(:authorize)
    # similar to what happens when you call authorize!(:show, @post)
    @controller.authorize!(authorization_action, resource_instance || resource_class_with_parent)
  end
end
```

As long as raising exceptions inside of `before_filter` stops controller action from being executed, failing to pass authorization here gets you redirected to your application's home url, shown 500 error page or whatever behaviour you defined for `CanCan::AccessDenied` handling.

On the other hand, in case you've passed authorization successfully, your action code gets executed. Now you've got access to instance variable (e.g. `@post`) which has been set up by `CanCan` at `load_resource` step.

Comment: How does it know whether to fetch a collection, or create or load an instance?

Comment: @mwfearnley for `:index` action, it loads `@things`, but for every other action, it loads `@thing` (based on the `:id`)